# How to get the SUM without exponent in xmlstarlet?

Tags: sum, xmlstarlet

When using the SUM in xmlstarlet. 
I get the result in exponent.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "sum(VM_POOL/VM/MONITORING/MEMORY)"/tmp/file.xml 
3.058237512e+09
```

If I get the SUM using awk. I get the desired numeral.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v VM_POOL/VM/MONITORING/MEMORY /tmp/file.xml|awk '{u = u+$1}; END { print u }'
3058237512
```

How to get these numeral use only xmlstarlet?

Sample input data

```
<VM_POOL>
  .....
  <VM>
   <ID>1111</ID>
   <MONITORING>
     <MEMORY><![CDATA[2153128]]></MEMORY>
   </MONITORING>
  </VM>
  <VM>
   <ID>1112</ID>
   <MONITORING>
      <MEMORY><![CDATA[2153128]]></MEMORY>
   </MONITORING>
  </VM>
  .....
</VM_POOL>
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.